# Firebase database returning data out of the filter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase is returning data that doesn't match the query I want.

My domain class is something like

```
Event {

long eventDate
//many other irrelevant stuff
}
```

I wish to retrieve the 10 next events (after today) (SQL like would be:
`Select * from event e where e.eventDate > now() order by e.eventDate ASC limit 10`

then I'm doing the following request:

```
fire.child("event").orderByChild("eventDate").startAt(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1, "eventDate").limitToFirst(10).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Giveaway> page = new ArrayList<>(PAGE_SIZE);

            for (DataSnapshot evs : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Event da = evs.getValue(Event.class);
                    long s = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long w = da.eventDate;
        System.out.println(s < w); //IN APP CHECK
]
    }}
```

but all results this query returns print `false`

Comment: Where does it return `false`? Please add the corresponding code.

Comment: @AlexMamo, it doesn't return false, it returns values and when I check  `System.out.println(s < w);` it always print false... check the code

Comment: So it's the correct behaviour since the current timestamp cannot be less than a timestamp from the past, right?

Comment: @AlexMamo did you read my question at all? I WANT EVENTS HAPPENING AFTER NOW... so current timestamp MUST be lower than eventDate

Comment: So are you sure the `w` is set at a later time? Can you provide us a concrete example from your database? I'm affraid that if statement is not misteken.

Comment: i am sure that w is set a later time, anyway if it wasn't and firebase was runing under some basic logic this query would return EMPTY... but is returning exaclty the oposite what is supposed to return

Comment: Oh, I understand now. I'll write you an answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering it for the sake of someone have the same problem in future as google's apis are way out counter intuitive

According to firebase:
  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query

> startAt(boolean value, String key) Create a query constrained to only
>   return child nodes with a value greater than or equal to the given
>   value, using the given orderBy directive or priority as default, and
>   additionally only child nodes with a key greater than or equal to the
>   given key.

so I tought `.startAt(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1, "eventDate")` would return the nodes with child `eventDate` greater than `System.currentTimeMillis() + 1` but actually the second paramenter on `startAt` is used to compare the key of each node

so this was making the logic of my query be tottally corrupted

removing the second parameter of `startAt` made the return be as expected

Comment: Good to hear that you found the cause of the problem Rafael. The second parameter to `startAt()` is indeed only used to disambiguate in case of multiple matches. Also see https://stackoverflow.com//45625553, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44895055

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, what still is way counter intuitive, 100% of devs would prefer to have a way to assign a second order parameter (as any sql db allows you to order by many columns) or simple `startAt` something different than the order parameters....